# JAVA File Tree Model slow for pendrive

Tags: java, performance, scroll, treemodel, usb-drive

I'm developing an application which will work with external memories accessed through USB a lot.
I've implemented TreeModel for browsing directories on disks. It works great for:

- local discs on Ubuntu
- connected external memories on Ubuntu
- local discs on Windows 7

but it sucks for connected external memories on Windows 7 and I don't know why. Scrolling a JTree with this model with pendrive as a root is very glitchy. At the beginning I've thought that `listFiles()` from java.io.File is slow for pendrive so I've added some kind of caching to model but it didn't work - scrolling still sucks.

I've just noticed that it have something to do with Look&Feel. For system L&F on Windows it sucks BAD, for Nimbus L&F it is not that bad but still not perfect.

FileTreeModel:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class FileTreeModel implements TreeModel {

    private File root;
    private boolean onlyFolders;
    private boolean showHidden;
    private final Object LEAF = new Serializable() {
    };
    private Map<File, Object> map;
    private LinkedList<TreeModelListener> listeners = new LinkedList<>();
    private FileFilter directoryFilter = new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(java.io.File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    };

    public FileTreeModel(File root, boolean onlyFolders, boolean showHidden) {
        this.root = root;
        this.onlyFolders = onlyFolders;
        this.showHidden = showHidden;
        this.map = new HashMap();
    }

    public FileTreeModel() {
    }

    public boolean isShowHidden() {
        return showHidden;
    }

    public void setShowHidden(boolean showHidden) {
        this.showHidden = showHidden;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(File root) {
        Object oldRoot = this.root;
        this.root = root;
        map.clear();
        TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(root, new Object[]{root});
        for (TreeModelListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.treeStructureChanged(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        return ((File) node).isFile();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        if (parent instanceof java.io.File && ((java.io.File) parent).canRead()) {
            List<File> files = children(parent);
            int result = 0;
            for (java.io.File file : files) {
                if (((file.isDirectory() && onlyFolders) || !onlyFolders)
                        && ((!file.isHidden() && !showHidden) || showHidden)) {
                    result++;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        if (parent instanceof java.io.File) {
            List<File> files = children(parent);
            List<java.io.File> resultFiles = new LinkedList<>();
            for (java.io.File file : files) {
                if (((file.isDirectory() && onlyFolders) || !onlyFolders)
                        && ((!file.isHidden() && !showHidden) || showHidden)) {
                    resultFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
            return resultFiles.get(index);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        if (parent instanceof java.io.File) {
            List<File> files = children(parent);
            List<java.io.File> resultFiles = new LinkedList<>();
            for (java.io.File file : files) {
                if (((file.isDirectory() && onlyFolders) || !onlyFolders)
                        && ((!file.isHidden() && !showHidden) || showHidden)) {
                    resultFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
            return resultFiles.indexOf(child);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newvalue) {
    }

    @Override
    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    //============================PRIVATE METHODS===============================
    protected List<File> children(Object node) {
        File f = (File) node;
        Object value = map.get(f);
        if (value == LEAF) {
            return null;
        }
        List children = (List) value;
        if (children == null) {
            File[] c = f.listFiles();
            if (c != null) {
                children = new ArrayList(c.length);
                for (int len = c.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    children.add(c[i]);
                    if (!c[i].isDirectory()) {
                        map.put(c[i], LEAF);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                children = new ArrayList(0);
            }
            map.put(f, children);
        }
        return children;
    }
}
```

Sample form:

```
import folderlist.model.treemodels.FileTreeModel;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTree1 = new javax.swing.JTree();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Refresh");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTree1.setModel(new FileTreeModel());
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTree1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 173, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 189, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(getAvailableRoots());
        jComboBox1.setModel(model);
    }

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        File choosenRoot = (File) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        if (choosenRoot != null) {
            FileTreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(choosenRoot, false, true);
            jTree1.setModel(model);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
//            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
//                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
//                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private Vector<File> getAvailableRoots() {
        Vector<File> v = new Vector<File>(10, 1);
        File userHome = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        if (userHome.isDirectory()) {
            v.addElement(userHome);
        }
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();
        for (File root : roots) {
            v.addElement(root);
        }
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        boolean isUnix = (os.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || os.indexOf("nux") >= 0);
        if (isUnix) {
            roots = new File("/media").listFiles();
            for (File root : roots) {
                v.addElement(root);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTree jTree1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two issues (that I can se) are:

1. Your not caching your results. File listing is an expensive operation, it takes time. On external devices even more so. Once you've listed a directory, maintain the list. If you're using Java 7, you can use the [Fie Watcher Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), otherwise, you're going to need to provide a refresh option.
2. You should off load the loading of the nodes children tO a ackground task.  Take a look at http://www.jroller.com/Thierry/entry/swing_lazy_loading_in_a & http://www.jroller.com/Thierry/entry/swing_lazy_loading_in_jtree . While not perfect, try provide a good idea

**UPDATE**

When you have a look at the code, there is a lot going on.  For a individual node, probably nothing significant, but when you start getting a few nodes, the delay will start to become noticeable.

So every time the tree needs to repaint, it's crawling through each individual node a call `getChildCount`, `getChildren` and/or `getChildAt`.  Each of these methods are essentially doing the same thing, over and over again.

```
@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    if (parent instanceof java.io.File && ((java.io.File) parent).canRead()) {
        List<File> files = children(parent);
        int result = 0;
        for (java.io.File file : files) {
            if (((file.isDirectory() && onlyFolders) || !onlyFolders)
                    && ((!file.isHidden() && !showHidden) || showHidden)) {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    if (parent instanceof java.io.File) {
        List<File> files = children(parent);
        List<java.io.File> resultFiles = new LinkedList<>();
        for (java.io.File file : files) {
            if (((file.isDirectory() && onlyFolders) || !onlyFolders)
                    && ((!file.isHidden() && !showHidden) || showHidden)) {
                resultFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
        return resultFiles.get(index);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It would be better to have a sub model that contained a list of all the File's and then based on the properties (`showHidden` & `onlyFolders`) produce a cached sub model which could then be used to produce the results from each call.

For example

```
@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    int count = 0;
    if (parent instanceof java.io.File && ((java.io.File) parent).canRead()) {
        count = fileModel.getFilteredFiles().size();
    }
    return count;
}
```

That's just a sugesstion.

Also, from recent experience, `File.canRead()` & `File.canWrite()` can return false positives on Windows 7 machines where the UAC is active :P

Comment: 1. I am caching results. Look closer - [code](children()) method. Or am I missing something? <br/>
2. Lazy loading is good idea, but is it nessesary? Loading time is not that long - it is under a second, but maybe you're right.. I'll give it a look.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected, from the code, it doesn't appear to be cached.

Comment: I think you're right about this computations. I will re-code it.  About caching. I assume that you have in mind that I've implemented my own cache by using Map without any caching algorithms or capacity management (you made me read about this - thanks). What do you think? It would be better to use some fremawork or implement very simple cache on my own? I wonder if advenced algorithms wouldn't be unnecesarilly time consuming?